# What is this mass of ground cover with rose-pink "bead" head flowers

Tags: identification, ground-cover

I have this ground cover plant all over my mostly shady back yard. It is tiny, flat, close to the ground with dark green pointy leaves and a little taller stem with rosy pink "bead" flowers on top. I have not been able to identify this for years!
Location: Southern New Jersey

Comment: Can you add a photograph please....

Comment: Both a closeup and a distance shot would be great.

Comment: Please add a picture and we will help you solve the identification.

Answer (score 0):

Well,  I'm going to go out on a limb here, sight unseen, and answer that it's [partridgeberry (mitchella repens)](http://www.whatgrowsthere.com/grow/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Mitchella_repens_2.jpg).